# Need URL(hyper link) in one of the solr field

Tags: solr

I am trying to do indexing on PDF documents with TIKA.

I am using `org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument()` to add different fields to documents like `id`, `title`, `author`, `url`.
In URL field I am giving path of the file which is going to be indexded.
Currently my local system path:

```
C:/Users/abcd/workspace/SOLRRichDocs/resources/apache-solr-ref-guide-5.1-001.pdf
```

But in output this field is simply coming as text (not clickable).
I have the requirement to output in "url" field as hyperlink so that I can go to the document.

This is the output I am getting:

```
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
  <doc>
    <str name="id">24d0331c-7db8-42c0-ae57-f0a87b4cc798</str>
    <str name="url">C:/Users/abcd/workspace/SOLRRichDocs/resources/apache-solr-ref-guide-5.1-001.pdf</str>
    <long name="_version_">1507935693954875392</long></doc>
</result>
```

I need hyperlink in url field.

Could you all experts share your Inputs.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the same you need add the code at the client end.
Solr will give the plain text that is been stored...
Like show the url in the HTML  tag..

for example

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
```

here u can add the text from the solr response...and it would a hyperlink for you.

Comment: As per my understanding you are suggesting- we can not get this functionality in SOLR.we have to take care in this UI/client application that we will be using on top of that.

Comment: Both Solr's Transformer and Highlighter feature don't support adding html tags in query time. At least not for a single specified field. It seems that the only solution is to insert download links in the field like:

`<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>`

See [Transformers](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/transforming-result-documents.html) and [Highlighter's](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/highlighting.html) doc for more.